# LWC lightning-tab content not getting refresh on UI

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-tab

On child Component if I update a value of any property, it gets refreshed on first tab but second tab is content is showing the old values only while property is already marked @track (same property working fine with first tab)

```
<lightning-tab value="closed" onactive={clickClosedTab} icon-name="custom:custom16" label="My Completed Tasks">
    <c-task-list id="secondTab" task-filter-type="closed"></c-task-list>
</lightning-tab>

<lightning-tab value="open" onactive={clickOpenTab} icon-name="custom:custom18" label="My Open Tasks">
    <c-task-list id="firstTab" task-filter-type="open"></c-task-list>
</lightning-tab>
```

Below is the code for c-task-list child component:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import {
    LightningElement, track, api
} from "lwc";
import getAllTasks from "@salesforce/apex/TransationCheckListController_Appirio.getAllTasks";

import updateTask from "@salesforce/apex/TransationCheckListController_Appirio.updateTask";

import Id from "@salesforce/user/Id";

export default class TransitionchecklistComp extends LightningElement {
    @api taskFilterType;

    userId = Id;

    @track mapAllTasks;
    @track mapCompletedTasks;

    @track countRecords = 0;


    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('connectedCallback: ' + this.taskFilterType);
        if(this.taskFilterType === 'open'){

        this.loaddata('open');
        }
        if(this.taskFilterType === 'closed'){
        this.loaddata('closed');
        }
    }

    @api
    loadTab(tabName) {
       //window.console.log("child method: " + tabName);
       this.taskFilterType = tabName;
        this.loaddata();


    }

    get mapOfListValues(){
        if(this.taskFilterType === 'open'){
            return this.mapAllTasks;
            }
            if(this.taskFilterType === 'closed'){
            return this.mapCompletedTasks;
            } 
            return null;
    }


    loaddata() {
        getAllTasks({
                recordId: this.userId,
                taskstatus: this.taskFilterType
            })
            .then(result => {
                window.console.log(result);

                if (result) {

                    this.countRecords = 0;
                    this.mapAllTasks = [];
                    this.mapCompletedTasks = [];

                    // Converting apex map into Javascript array. - sunil appirio
                    for (let key in result) {
                        // Preventing unexcepted data
                        if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            // Filtering the data in the loop

                            let lstTaskObj = [];
                            lstTaskObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[key]));

                            // adding a URL field into Task list
                            for (let i = 0; i < lstTaskObj.length; i++) {
                                this.countRecords = this.countRecords + 1;
                                lstTaskObj[i].url =
                                    "/StudentLifeApp/s/taskdetailpage?recordId=" +
                                    lstTaskObj[i].Id +
                                    "&parentPage=transition-checklist";
                                //lstTaskObj[i].taskCount = lstTaskObj[i].Id + "[5 Tasks]";
                            }

                            if(this.taskFilterType === 'open'){
                                this.mapAllTasks.push({
                                    key: key,
                                    value: lstTaskObj
                                });
                            }
                            if(this.taskFilterType === 'closed'){
                                this.mapCompletedTasks.push({
                                    key: key,
                                    value: lstTaskObj
                                });
                            }
                            this.showLoadingSpinner = false;
                        }
                    }

                    console.log('Total Records: ' + this.countRecords + ' :: ' + this.taskFilterType);
                }


            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                this.payload = undefined;
            });
    }

    // Getting selected rows
    getSelectedRecords(event) {
        window.console.log("**Checkbox checkEvent " + event.target.checked);
        window.console.log("**Checkbox checkEvent target " + event.target.value);

        //Get Checked Row value
        const checked = Array.from(
                this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-input")
            )
            // Filter to only checked items
            .filter(element => element.checked)
            // Map to their labels
            .map(element => element.value);
        window.console.log("**Checkbox checkEvent Ids " + checked);
        this.selectedRecords = checked;
        window.console.log(
            "**Checkbox checkEvent collection " + this.selectedRecords
        );
    }

    //update Task
    updateRecordsButton() {
        //this.showLoadingSpinner = true;
        window.console.log("*Current Reocrd--2*" + this.selectedRecords.length);
        if (this.selectedRecords != null && this.selectedRecords.length > 0) {
            window.console.log("*Current Reocrd--1*" + this.selectedRecords);
            updateTask({
                    recordId: this.selectedRecords
                })
                .then(result => {
                    this.selectedRecords = [];

                    console.log(result);
                    if(this.taskFilterType === 'open'){
                        this.loaddata('open');

                        }
                        if(this.taskFilterType === 'closed'){
                        this.loaddata('closed');

                        }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    window.console.log(error);
                    this.error = error;
                });
        } else {
            console.log("err");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a look at [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for details on how best to ask a question to get an answer. This typically means including more of your code to give folks a chance to understand what you are doing and to help identify any issues with it. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/278659/edit) your question and add the relevant detail. Thanks.

Comment: can you show code of c-task-list ?

Comment: @salesforce-sas updated question with child component JS file.